# How to setup port forwarding between two public servers (ufw, debian)

Tags: debian, iptables, port-forwarding, ufw

I have `SERVER1` and `SERVER2`.

- Both Debian9, both with `ufw`.
- I have `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` enabled on both servers.
- `SERVER1` have Apache2 running on ports 80 and 443.

I need to forward ports 80 and 443 from `SERVER2` to `SERVER1`, but my configuration not working and I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Top of `/etc/ufw/before.rules` on `SERVER2`:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to SERVER1:80
COMMIT
```

I restarted ufw + `sysctl -p`

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to setup something on `SERVER1` too?

Comment: If server2
 doesn't see the incoming traffic AND the return traffic when doing this NAT, it can't work like this. You're used to do this when the server is a router where it has "control" over the LAN behind. If it's not, everything gets more complex

Comment: both servers are on public internet on eth0, so youre right. How to do it then? I need to just bounce packets from SERVER2 to SERVER1

Comment: I'll leave the answer to somebody having thoughts about this. There are probably multiple methods (SNAT and lose source IP, tunnel, reverse proxy etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answer to my original question, but I managed to do it with Apache2 proxy. I installed Apache2 on `SERVER2` (and enabled proxy) and changed configs to proxy connection.

default.conf

```
ProxyPass / http://SERVER1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://SERVER1/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

default-ssl.conf

```
ProxyPass / https://SERVER1/
ProxyPassReverse / https://SERVER1/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```